# NextJS/Image: "url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid

Tags: next.js, strapi, nextjs-image

I am trying to fetch images from Strapi into my NextJS Application, but whatever I am trying to do I am always getting the error

> "url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid"

The console is stating:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
> (Bad Request)

I already updated "next" to the latest version:

[image: package.json configuration]

[image: Bad request]

Here is my Snippet from my Image Code:

[image: Snippet NextJS/Image Code]

What else can I try to not receive an error anymore?

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases this the error with server itself where your images are hosted. check the URL in new tab to see if it loads appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

May it help someone, I had this issue because I had changed the names of the properties of the response object received from the api from its default case (snake_case) to camelCase while generating a typescript type for it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you didn't add the source to your image domain, probably you should read more on the Image docs here https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

To get rid of this error, create a 'next.config.js' file in the root of your project. Add Domain of all images except local host to the domains array, like so:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: [
      "platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com", //facebook
      "firebasestorage.googleapis.com", //firebase-storage
      "scontent-atl3-2.xx.fbcdn.net", //facebook
      "pbs.twimg.com", //twitter
    ],
  },
};
```

So in your case since, you're fetching from an external source, don't include 'localhost'